# Test Based on Label of Encoded Variable

Tags: variables, label, stata, encode

Say I have a string variable, `animal`, that takes on values `dog`, `cat`, and `horse`. I encode this string variable to get `animal2`. How can I then test `animal2` using the label as opposed to the actual numeric values?

In other words, I can do a logical test on `animal` as follows:

```
gen dog = animal=="dog"
```

But I get an error if I do the same thing with `animal2`:

```
gen dog2 = animal2=="dog"
```

How can I perform this test using the label? Pseudocode is as follows:

```
gen dog2 = label(animal2)=="dog"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic technique here is documented at [U] 13.11 (e.g. [here](http://www.stata.com/manuals14/u13.pdf)).

Here is an example:

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. count if foreign=="Domestic":origin
  52

. count if foreign=="Domestic":`: val label foreign'
  52
```

The last example shows a way of looking up the value label name, which may be useful in programs or do-files.